# How to interrupt a UIView Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

In the following code, I have a view that presents information for two seconds and then it animates and disappears. What I would like to be able to do is give the user the ability close the view by swiping the view before animation has finished. My problem is that the view doesn't recognize the gesture when the animation is in progress.

How can I make the view recognize the swipe gesture while an animation is in progress?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    closeMyViewWithAnimation()
}

func closeMyViewWithAnimation(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.myView.frame.origin.y = 0 - self.myView.frame.height
    }, completion:{ finished in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}

/// This gestures is not recognized while the closeMyViewWithAnimation
/// is in progress. How can I make the view to recognize this gesture?
@IBAction func closeMyViewWithGesture(_ sender: Any) {

    viewAddToCartAlert.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.myView.frame.origin.y = 0 - self.myView.frame.height
    }, completion:{ finished in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

### EDIT:

I ended up using a timer to delay the animation in `viewDidAppear` so the animation doesn't start immediately allowing the user to swipe.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(closeMyViewWithAnimation), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of problem that UIViewPropertyAnimator solves.

Comment: Try enabling user interaction during the animation: by using `options: [.curveEaseIn, .allowUserInteraction]`

Comment: @vacawama I tried adding `options: [.curveEaseIn, .allowUserInteraction]` to my animation but it didn't work. @ matt - I couldn't figure out how to use the `UIViewPropertyAnimator `.  I ended up using a timer (see edited question).